# Como pegar um json em um servidor externo com Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

Olá galera estou precisando pegar um json com javascript em um servidor externo!
Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Você quer dizer que o servidor externo lhe dá um JSON como resposta e você quer usar esse JSON no seu javascript?

Comment: É isto que você procura? http://jsfiddle.net/LFWn6/

Comment: Isso mesmo amigo!Estou quebrando a cabeça com isso.

Answer (score 2):

O que você precisa é fazer uma chamada AJAX...

Exemplo

```
var endereco = 'http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two';
$.ajax({
    url: endereco,
    complete: function(res){
        var meuJSON = JSON.parse(res.responseText);
        console.log(meuJSON); 
    }
});
```

### [Demo live](http://jsfiddle.net/p6cS4/)

Um pedido/chamada ajax permite interagir com o "lado do servidor". Assim, código do lado do cliente pode ir buscar informação a um servidor. O mesmo, ou um exterior quando o mesmo permitir.

O que precisa também é fazer o parse/conversão dos dados recebidos para um objecto JSON. O Javascript tem uma função nativa para isso, o [**JSON.parse()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Neste exemplo usei jQuery, também é possível com outras bibliotecas ou mesmo javascript puro.

Comment: Sergio, isso funciona se a chamada for no mesmo servidor que a url requisitada. Mas como fazer quando a url é em outro servidor? Ex.: meu site, onde a chamada é feita, é http://meusite.com.br. A url para execução do assincrona seria http://outroservidor.com.br. Isso, por padrão, retorna um erro, porto que são chamadas assincronas em servidores diferentes. Como proceder, em ambos os lados? Uso: desenvolvimento de API.

Comment: @Szag-Ot nesse  caso deves ter um problema de CORS. Se tens controlo sobre o outro site podes ativar o CORS, se não podes usar JSONP, dá uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70267/129

Answer (score -1):

Foi o que eu consegui achar resposta SO inglês ->

Você pode fazer isso assim:

```
function insertReply(content) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = content;
}

// create script element
var script = document.createElement('script');
// assing src with callback name
script.src = 'http://url.to.json?callback=insertReply';
// insert script to document and load content
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Mas fonte deve estar ciente de que você quer que ele chame a função passada como parâmetro de retorno de chamada para ele.

Com o Google API que seria parecido com este:

```
function insertReply(content) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = content;
}

// create script element
var script = document.createElement('script');
// assing src with callback name
script.src = 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/text/en/bob_dylan?callback=insertReply';
// insert script to document and load content
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Confira como os dados parece que quando você passar de retorno de chamada para a API do Google:

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/text/en/bob_dylan?callback=insertReply

Aqui é muito boa explicação de JSONP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

**resposta traduzida de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922101/**