# Capturar dados input Iframe

Tags: html5

Bom, numa página tenho um iframe, nele é exibido parte do outro site meu, estão em servidores diferentes, o que preciso é acessar o input do iframe e enviar para uma variavel javascript de minha página, sendo que pelo Iframe não tem como enviar por Post ou GET. Pelo que já li, os browsers por questão de segurança não permitem isso, mas, vi algo relacionado a Post Messenger do HTML5, mas, não encontrei nada de documentação ou que explique como funciona.

Alguem já precisou e solucionou este problema?

Comment: A página que está dentro do iFrame está no mesmo domínio?

Comment: Não, estão em dominios e servidores diferentes

Comment: Então sugiro usares [JSONP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70267/129), caso ambas as páginas sejam tuas e tenhas aceso a uma linguagem de servidor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digamos que você tenha dois sites em dominios diferentes, onde o cliente acessar o `dominio1.com` e o mesmo possui um iFrame apontado para o `dominio2.com`.

Para o dominio `dominio2.com` enviar uma mensagem para o `dominio1.com` é necessario usar o método `.postMessage()`

```
var outraJanela = window.parent;
var data = { ... }; //objeto que será enviado;
var json = JSON.stringify(data);
outraJanela.postMessage(json, "http://dominio1.com");
```

note que especificamos o dominio que será o alvo, isto é para evitar que o seu dominio se comunique com dominios indesejados, como por exemplo `dominio-falso.com`.

agora em `dominio1.com` você precisa adicionar um listener para receber a mensagem enviada por `dominio2.com`

```
window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
    if (event.origin === "http://dominio2.com") {
        var data = JSON.parse(event.data); // os dados enviados por dominio2
    }
});
```

Mais uma vez é necessario verificar quem enviou a mensagem, por isto verificamos ser a origem é a esperada, no caso `dominio2.com`.

caso você precise enviar uma mensagem de confimação para o `dominio2.com`, basta fazer o seguinte:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
    if (event.origin === "http://dominio2.com") {
        var data = JSON.parse(event.data); // os dados enviados por dominio2
        event.source.postMessage("OK", event.origin);
    }
});
```

lembrando que será preciso adicionar `window.addEventListener("message", ...)` em `dominio2.com` para que ele possa receber a mensagem de confimação.