# Como consumir esse JSON com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

Como faço para consumir [essa URL](https://client-demo-accounts-2.bootstrap.fyre.co/bs3/v3.1/client-demo-accounts-2.fyre.co/379221/MjAxNjAxMjcxMjQyOmRlc2lnbmVyLWFwcC0xNDUzODQwMjgxODk0/init) usando JavaScript?

> https://client-demo-accounts-2.bootstrap.fyre.co/bs3/v3.1/client-demo-accounts-2.fyre.co/379221/MjAxNjAxMjcxMjQyOmRlc2lnbmVyLWFwcC0xNDUzODQwMjgxODk0/init

Comment: Se você utilizará apenas `JavaScript` veja as respostas [dessa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3167/requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ajax-com-javascript-puro-sem-apis) pegunta.

Comment: Importante ler [O que é JSONP e como funciona?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/70267/o-que-%C3%A9-o-jsonp-e-como-funciona)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando apenas JavaScript:

```js
var url = "https://client-demo-accounts-2.bootstrap.fyre.co/bs3/v3.1/client-demo-accounts-2.fyre.co/379221/MjAxNjAxMjcxMjQyOmRlc2lnbmVyLWFwcC0xNDUzODQwMjgxODk0/init";

var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.open("GET", url);
httpRequest.responseType = "json";
httpRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (httpRequest.readyState == 4){
    if (httpRequest.status == 200){
      console.log(httpRequest.response);
      console.log(httpRequest.response.headDocument);
      console.log(httpRequest.response.headDocument.authors);
      console.log(httpRequest.response.headDocument.content);
    } else {
    
    }
  }
});

httpRequest.send();
```

O exemplo acima não vai funcionar no *snippet* do SOpt, então você pode conferir o mesmo no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TobyMosque/xtk52m1o/)

Comment: Está dando erro por não ser da mesma origem. Por isso citei a questão do JSONP. Eu sei que o AP não especificou a questão de a url ser interna ou externa. Foi bom ter acontecido isso.

Comment: Wallace, o erro ocorre devido uma escolha da arquitetura do SO, se executar o codigo acima no JSFiddle ele irá funcionar sem problemas.

Comment: Isso eu entendi. Mas eu quero saber do AP. Se ele fizer isso no código dele, vai dar no mesmo (o mesmo erro deu seu código). Por isso quero saber se o domínio dele está marcado como `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Comment: Amigo, como coloco isso e uma <li> ??

Comment: @TobyMosque pode deixar. Só por ele ter marcado a sua resposta, percebi que resolveu o problema dele. Abraços :D

Comment: @BrunoBafilli, o que você quer jogar dentro de uma li? você pode adicionar um template do HTML que você quer montar?

Answer (score 4):

Por conta da restrição do CORS, você não pode fazer uma requisição `ajax` comum.

Nesse caso, para driblar esse problema, você poderá usar um [JSONP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/70267/o-que-%C3%A9-o-jsonp-e-como-funciona).

Nesse caso, vou exemplificar com o `JSONP` do jQuery.

```
var url = 'https://client-demo-accounts-2.bootstrap.fyre.co/bs3/v3.1/client-demo-accounts-2.fyre.co/379221/MjAxNjAxMjcxMjQyOmRlc2lnbmVyLWFwcC0xNDUzODQwMjgxODk0/init';
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  }

});
```

Testei na url informada e ele aceitou perfeitamente o uso de `JSONP`.

Comment: eu nao conheco, eu colocaria url: https://client-demo-accounts-2.bootstrap.fyre.co/bs3/v3.1/client-demo-accounts-2.fyre.co/379221/MjAxNjAxMjcxMjQyOmRlc2lnbmVyLWFwcC0xNDUzODQwMjgxODk0/init ??

Comment: Sim. A url completa você coloca no lugar da url

Comment: Não vou explicar o que é jsonp, mas vou adicionar a referência na resposta. Por favor, considere ler as respostas ;). É importante. E não se esqueça de votar nas que você achar interessante

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues sempre me perdo com esses "códigos fictícios", obrigado.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, se não há a intenção de enviar uma função de callback no padding, então pq usar `JSONP` ao invés de `JSON`?

Comment: @TobyMosque a intenção é evitar o bloqueio da requisição que é feita para domínios diferentes.

Comment: De qualquer forma, vou manter a resposta, pois algumas pessoas ainda não sabem que é bloqueado fazer requisições ajax para domínios diferentes, a não ser que ele esteja marcado como Access-Control-Allow-Origin no site onde se faz a requisição.