# Erro ao pegar dados da API

Tags: php, api

Não estou conseguindo pegar os dados de uma determinada API alguem pode me ajudar? Já tentei de varias maneiras.
o erro que esta dando é :

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\index.php on line 7

```
<?php
$api=file_get_contents("https://api.bf4stats.com/api/playerInfo?plat=pc&name=1ApRiL&output=js");
$defuse=json_decode($api);

echo $defuse->player->name;

?>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que é o JSONP e como funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/70267/o-que-%c3%a9-o-jsonp-e-como-funciona)

Comment: No seu caso, acho que é só alterar a URL pra `&output=json` que seu código funciona

Answer (score 0):

O valor **output** passado como parametro na url não deve ser js, deveria ser json. A função json_decode, como você utilizou, não vai interpretar o resultado da sua requisição como um json valido. Coloque na url output=json.

```
<?php
$api=file_get_contents("https://api.bf4stats.com/api/playerInfo?plat=pc&name=1ApRiL&output=json");
$defuse=json_decode($api);

echo $defuse->player->name;

?>
```

Comment: Perfeito, falta de atenção desde já agradeço agora funcionou!!